# Testing a chrome extension using Testcafe with switchToIframe

Tags: testing, iframe, google-chrome-extension, automated-tests, testcafe

I've currently got an extension running on testcafe within chrome by having the extension installed on chrome and running: `testcafe chrome:userProfile test.js`

The `content_script` in my extension injects an iframe pointing to the `web_accessible_resource` index.html asset. However when I switch to the iframe context using `t.switchToIframe` testcafe returns "Content of the iframe to which you are switching did not load"

From what I can see it looks like testcafe-hammerhead isn't rewriting the iframe src when it's in the format of `chrome-extension://[PACKAGE ID]/[PATH])` so I've tried changing the url to point to a url i.e. localhost:8080/index.html but this doesn't work either.

If I create an html file inject the iframe using a js file I'm able to get the test to run and interact with the iframe. Therefore I think it's related to how content scripts are run and how they inject content in to the DOM.

Has anyone else run in to this issue/have any better suggestions on how to write tests for extensions in general?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, TestCafe doesn't support browser extension testing. TestCafe was designed for cross-browser HTML5 web app testing, so it needs a lot of improvements to cover browser-specific extension APIs.

I suggest you create an issue in the https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe repository and add +1 to it. If it receives enough votes, we might consider its implementation.